# What is the correct answer for cross entropy in this case?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, cross-entropy

I have two neural networks: NN1 and NN2, predicting Dog and Cat. The probabilities are below:

```
        NN1    NN2
Dog 1   0.9    0.6     
Cat 0   0.1    0.4

Dog 0   0.1    0.3     
Cat 1   0.9    0.7 

Dog 1   0.4    0.1     
Cat 0   0.6    0.9
```

I calculated Cross Entropy for NN1 as below:

-1*ln(0.9) -1*ln(0.9) -1*ln(0.4) = 1.12

But the answer is 0.38 for NN1 and 1.06 for NN2. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to divide by 3, as formally cross entropy is the average of each point's contribution.

To be clear, the $n$ is only necessary when you have test observations. The usual formula is $H:=-\sum_{x}p(x)\log(q(x))$, where the sum (or integral in the continuous case) is over the *state space*, so if you want to make an *empirical* estimate of cross entropy over your training set, then the formula is $H:=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i\log(f(x_i))$, where $x_i$ is each datapoint. For example if $P(1)=0.3$, then you typicall expect to see 30% of your data with $y=1$, so then out of 100 samples, you'd expect 30 $Y$'s, and $30/100=0.3$.

The logic is the same as say, finding the average of $n$ numbers from a distribution $p(x)$.

Note that many implementations don't bother dividing by $n$, since it is immaterial in the optimization that takes place to extremize $H$.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Can you show me a link for that info? I did not find any `divide by n` in any Cross Entropy formula

Comment: @DamingLu: See edit.